# Python Selenium error when trying to launch the Firefox browser

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) and am trying to launch the Firefox browser in headless mode using Selenium WebDriver in Python as below -

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/root/geckodriver')
```

With this, I am getting the below error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

I have installed `Geckodriver` using the below code -

```
 wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.10.0/geckodriver-v0.10.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

I have also tried with v-0.24.0, but I was not successful.

My Selenium version is 3.141.0.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: Yes indeed! many thanks

Comment: Check that too if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340554/how-to-pass-a-headless-option-for-my-driver-using-java-and-selenium/54340648#54340648